# NSArrayController: Doesn't update bold attribute

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

I have a tableview bound to a NSArrayController. The ArrayController gets it´s data from an array `[NSObject]`:

```
class Fruits : NSObject {

    var name:String
    var price:Double

    // If I set 'isBold = true' here manually, 
    //the font in my tableview becomes bold (from start of the application).

    dynamic var isBold = false {
        didSet {
            print(isBold)
        }
    }

    override init() {
        name = "name"
        price = 0.0
    }

    init(name:String, price:Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }

}
```

So everything works fine as long as I set the ìsBold`value manually.

If I call in ViewController:

```
Fuits.init().isBold = true
tableView.reloadData()
```

The correct ìsBold`value is printed, but in the tableview nothing changes. Any ideas why the ArrayController doesn't notice the updated value?

[image]

EDIT:

I found a way how it is working. But maybe just a hint why it is not working like above. This solution works with iteration, I don´t think it is how it's supposed to be.

```
func changeBold(bold: Bool) {

        if bold == false {
            self.dataArray.forEach { fruit in
                fruit.isBold = false
            } else {
                self.dataArray.forEach { fruit in
                    fruit.isBold = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I misinterpreted what you had written. I thought the bindings settings panel was for the table view, not the table cell view. The rest of what you wrote makes more sense to me.

Your line `Fruits.init().isBold = true` is a bit odd syntax-wise, but the bigger point is that you're creating a new instance of `Fruits` and setting its bold attribute but not doing anything with the instance, so it goes away once it's out of scope. You need to change the property of the instance stored in the cell view's `objectValue` property (because that's the instance that's set by the bindings mechanism, which your cell view represents).

Also, be aware that "editing an object behind the controller's back" will also usually cause the symptom of changes not appearing in the UI. Example: if you remove an instance of `Fruits` from your array directly, you'd have to tell the array controller to refresh to see the changes (which can lose selection and scroll information in a table or some other UI state). Instead, you should access the *array controller's* `arrangedObjects` property and remove / add / insert there so the array controller is "aware" of the changes. You'll need to read a lot more on the bindings mechanism to understand when / why to make changes through a controller vs. directly, but it's an aspect of Cocoa Bindings of which you **must** be aware.

Comment: I set the controller’s object class to `Fruits`, otherwise the tableview would't get populated. I don´t exacrtly understand what you mean with `arrangedObjects` controller. Is the binding not right like I showed in the picture?

Comment: I found a way, also I don't think it's the proper way. See EDIT.

Comment: Your edit works only because you're operating on the actual instances of `Fruits` in your array controller.

Comment: So there is  a better solution? I must confess I don't really know how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: You have some reading to do. Regardless, the two-line `Fruits.init...` example only creates a temporary object, changes it, then lets it die; your second update works on the instances that live in the collection represented by the table cell views. You can't create some random "person", set its name, kill it, then expect the people standing over there to randomly have that person's name all of the sudden. Understand? If you want to rename one of the people in that group, grab that person and name him/her.

Comment: I think to 'rename' the person, that is exactly what I've done in my edited solution.

Comment: You say: "Instead, you should access the array controller's arrangedObjects property and remove / add / insert there so the array controller is "aware" of the changes.". This is wrong, you should mutate the content property. Or bind the content and mutate your own property in a KVO compliant way. Or better: use the methods of `NSArrayController` to add and remove objects.